# MongoDB partitioning

Tags: mongodb, database-partitioning, mongo-collection

Is there any semantics like collection partitioning in MongoDB? My data is very huge, per day more than 100 000 line data is recorded. in order to retrieve for the report takes some time for the selected device. If data gets logged daily, performance will be slow. how to optimize, i have created an index to improve performance.

Comment: Is "partitioning" different than [sharding](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/#sharding)?

Comment: I would assume it doesn't hurt if you add more details about your current setup, the performance, and what's your actual target for performance, because "improve performance" doesn't tell the scope of the problem.

Comment: Partitioning is the database process where very large tables(IN SQL) are divided into multiple smaller parts. By splitting a large table into smaller, individual tables, queries that access only a fraction of the data can run faster because there is less data to scan. The main of goal of partitioning is to aid in maintenance of large tables and to reduce the overall response time to read and load data for particular SQL operations.Is there any semantics like collection partitioning in MongoDB?